# How do I change the font size of a table column?

Tags: latex

I have a LaTeX table and would like the third column to be a different font size (smaller) than the others. I've always done this with a special-purpose macro that takes a parameter for each column and executes a font change for one of the columns. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the package `array` and specify the font just after the `\begin{tabular}`, e.g.:

```
\usepackage{array}
...
\begin{tabular}{|>{\small}c|>{\Huge}c}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{tabular}
```

this makes the first column font `small` and the second `Huge`. `>{decl}` is used before `l, r, c, p, m`, or `b` and inserts *decl* directly in from of each entry of the column.

You can find further details of this package (e.g. the `>{decl}` to put *decl* after each entry) [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/array.pdf).

Comment: Is there any way to do this for rows?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34225/different-font-sizes-for-different-rows-in-table